# Como colocar los float en otro color

Tags: float

Tengo una duda estoy haciendo un sitio en PHP/Laravel, CSS, HTML5 y un poco de Javascript y en el sitio hay un balance con 8 decimales y quiero poner los 0 de los decimales en otro color asi = [image: balance01] y cuando tenga un poco de balance quiero que los 0 al final de los decimales quede tambien de otro color asi = [image: balance02] pero solo cuando al final del decimal este en 0 si hay otros ceros pero no al final que tenga un color blanco asi = [image: balance03] y si es posible que cuando este la unidad completa los numeros sean un poco mas grandes que los decimales pero en fin no tengo idea de como empezar =//

THX

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask], ¿qué lenguaje?, ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Depende de en dónde quieras ponerlos así. Mientras no lo aclares ni nos cuentes cómo te ha ido con lo que has intentado para resolver tu pregunta, será difícil poder ayudarte